# make javascript variable visible in different functions

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, visibility

I need to declare the variable `a` somewhere, and using javascript technics make it visible for `f2` function being called inside the `f1` function. But being called directly (outside of the `f1` function) the `f2` function must fail to print a.
I can't use eval.
I can't change the f2 function.
I can change the f1 function however I want.
Is that possible at all?

```
function f1(var_name){
    f2();
}
function f2(){
    console.log(a);
}
f1();  // must log value of the a
f2();  // must not be able to log a
```

Comment: Why not just declare it globally?

Comment: @Manu then the last line which says it must not be able to log `a` would not function as OP stated.

Comment: why not use getter and setters?

Comment: Please look for and read about XY problem

Comment: No, not possible, `f2` will only have access to the scopes above it. you can't inject a variable into it other than through the use of .call/apply or arguments, neither of which would work without modifying how `f2` accesses `a` or making all calls to `f2` have access to `a`. You might be able to make a copy of `f2` though and modify it.

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to do?  What is `a`?  So, you want `f2()` to be able to access it, but not `f1()`?  Where are you setting this `a` value?

Comment: @jycr753 , are the getters and setters supported by all browsers.If so can you please write an answer.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do with this, maybe something like http://jsbin.com/cabozahuxi/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @KevinB, I guess you're right, though if I declare `this.a` inside the `f1`, then the Chrome's console prints `a`. So I decided to ask you.

Comment: @Amessihel won't work!

Comment: You can reconstruct f2 by retrieving its body in a string, then reval-it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Small work around.
Declare a globally and set to undefined.
Set the value of `a` before f2 function call inside f1. Set `a` to undefined after f2 call

```
var a = undefined;
function f1(var_name){
  a = 'this is a ';
  f2();
  a = undefined;
}
function f2(){
  console.log(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

why not using another global variable ?
You define a global variable `a` and in the function f1 you declare a new global variable `b = a`, call the f2 function that will print the `b` global variable, set the gobal variable `b` to NULL again.

With this, `b` is gonna be defined only during the f1 function and would have the value of the global `a` variable.

Answer (score 1):

This way will work only if f2() uses "this" already:
(in such case there will not be changes to add "this" support).

```
function f1(var_name){
    var scope = {a: var_name};
    f2.call(scope);
}
function f2(){
    console.log(this.a);
}

f1(123);  // must log value of the a
f2();  // must not be able to log a
```

Also you could think about functions overloading.

Comment: From the question: *I can't change the f2 function*. This requires a change to `f2()`.